# Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeSetId() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to give different styles [css] for  products of different **attribute sets**, so in view.phtml i am using below code & its working fine.

```
<?php
if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==20){ 
?>
<style>

.product-options 
{  
width: 30px; 
}

</style>

<?php
}
?>
```

but when i tried the same code in `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/catalog/product/view/options/type - select.phtml` , its giving below error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeSetId() on a non-object in line 

if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==20){
```

I added below code, still i have same error

```
$SetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup')->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default');
```

Comment: What is `$_product` in your `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme1/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml` file?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya its not displaying anything when i tried `echo $_product;`  , log error : `Undefined variable: _product`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Thanks a lot for your support......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace below code in option file

```
if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==20){
```

to:

```
$product = this->getProduct();
if($product->getAttributeSetId()==20){
```

Comment: i got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in`

Comment: @Baby in Magento, use $this->getProduct();

Comment: i tried like this : `<?php
$product = $this->getProduct();
if($_product->getAttributeSetId()==20){ 
?>
<style>` but still same error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeSetId() on a non-object in`

Comment: my mistake only, seems this worked for me : `$_product = $this->getProduct();` just a minute, i will confirm you......